# Change "Impact" to "Q&A Impact" and "Documentation Impact"

Tags: feature-request, documentation, profile-page

Right now, the *Impact* on my profile shows ~9k (2k on meta). This is about the same as before the documentation launch. I had far mor impact in docs (more than half of my rep is from there) than in Q&A, but it's still the same. It is not counting in views from doc contributions. How should these be handled?

I would say, they should be split up into Docs impact, and Q&A impact.

Maybe, rename the current Impact to Q&A impact and keep it this way, but as of now, it's inaccurate and confusing when considering Docs.

Comment: I would add some relevant [meta-tag:documentation]-related tags, as well as the [meta-tag:profile] tag.

Comment: also Q&A reputation and Documentation reputation

Comment: That assumes more than a few 100 views in your documentation posts.  ;)

Comment: @Yakk if it has over 500 upvotes (even 1k idk) i guess it has so ;) I have contributed important Parts to the c# linq/c#6/c# docs.

Comment: [This could be hindered by technical reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328703/addressing-documentation-repgateapocalypse)

Comment: Impact != Reputation

Comment: This is a feature request, unlike the linked questions. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Still, Rep != Impact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determining the view counts is a pretty low priority compared to the other large issues with the Documentation feature. They are [in the middle of rolling out another iteration of fixes and improvements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333420/documentation-update-august-29th?cb=1) while writing this.

Furthermore, part of the changes to the current Documentation feature is going to be contribution measurements. At the very least, the metrics for determining who gets credit for contributions is going to take precedence over how to categorize views for contributions.

Once the contribution considerations are in a more final state something along these lines may come in to play, but at the core I am still not sure why the impact would need to be split; it is a fairly unused metric.

Also to keep in mind, contribution recalculations will more than likely come with reputation recalculations.