# Will the Documentation reputation recalc cause a big drop in users' reputation graphs?

Tags: support, documentation, reputation

The [August 29 Documentation Update post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333420/4957418) states that a lot of current Documentation sourced rep will be removed in a massive re-calc.

> As with Q&A, if reputation is live on the site for 60 days then deletions (and rollbacks) will not remove it. This doesn't apply to changes to the rep system, so **the re-calc that accompanies this new system will affect all Documentation sourced rep no matter how old**.

(Emphasis mine)

---

> This system will remove about 50% of all Documentation sourced reputation

---

Will this cause a big drop in the reputation graphs, seen on the profiles of current documentation contributors, or will it be like the removed rep never even happened?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For a re-calc like this, it's a process of "rewriting history" - so the reputation graphs will be altered to look as if the reputation had always been at those values. You won't see a huge dip, or even any trace that your reputation dropped due to it, in your reputation history or graph. Your reputation and the events currently in your history will simply change to the new values.

Comment: Asking just out of technical curiosity: does the SO source code architecture using event sourcing and are using events to communicate with the rest of the domain models? Just if so, you can't "rewrite" the history since it already happened, meaning you will have to create new events (with minus rep. parameter) per stored domain objects/entities?

Comment: @kayess ...or you just call the massive stored procedure that does the recalc job and directly update the data within the DB.

Comment: @ken2k I hope that's just a funny procedural programming note, but ever since the fun isn't allowed (TM)... :P

Comment: @kayess SO does muck about in the DB sometimes.