# Can't track reputation drop

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, documentation, reputation

Today I've noticed a +400 rep drop, by searching in the rep section I can't track from where comes the drop, but I suspect that my contribution to this   **[angular performance](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angularjs/1921/profiling-and-performance/6270/7-simple-performance-improvements#t=201610280928385031248)** somehow does not count anymore, even with +350 char contribution,

Regarding sep 29 docs rep update :

> Major contributors are the creator of the example plus everyone who
>   has added at least 350 characters to an example

and [my contribution](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/60983?filter-tags=angularjs) to angular performance is more than that, and was not deleted or edited since July 27, so why I'm loosing this rep today ?

Comment: can you see something here? http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: nop I can't see from where comes the drop !!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333848/will-the-documentation-reputation-recalc-cause-a-big-drop-in-users-reputation-g?rq=1 maybe?

Comment: I'm aware of this and my rep have dropped from 4k to 2.7k, but today I can't track frome where comes the drop, there was no update to the rep section since 28th doc rep recalc

Comment: _"For a re-calc like this, it's a process of "rewriting history" - so the reputation graphs will be altered to look as if the reputation had always been at those values."_

Comment: @Cerbrus I know but I have a section in the doc where I contrebuted with more then 300 char and does not get considered !!

Comment: Maybe so but that is not going to account for a 400 reputation difference. That is something of a larger scale.

Comment: @Gimby this maybe answer my first question, but what about the angular performance contribution with more then 300 char not got counted ?

Comment: On what basis do you exactly know that this particular contribution does not count, especially since you state yourself you can't track the reputation drop?

Comment: because I can't see anymore the rep gained for this topic, 2 days ago I was able to see the +5 each time this topic get up voted !

Comment: @Gimby It's not about the 400 rep lost I just want to understand how the system works...

Comment: Yes but you need to calm down, pelting a comment every minute is not going to speed it up. I see where you're coming from; you did your contribution back in July 27th and the documentation in question has a cool 100 upvotes on it already so you probably got a nice amount of +5's on that over time. So I take back what I said - documentation is (still) warped enough that it might lead to a massive reputation drop like this if "something" happens. Not sure yet what that something is though, it kind of looks like a correction happened where you're no longer a major contributor.

Comment: This might be a bug.  If you look at your [controbutions page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4232386/ze-rubeus?tab=documentation&sort=contributions) you will see *[angularjs] Profiling and Performance* only shows up for sep 16, which also doesn't make sense since you second edit was on the 17th.  It almost looks like it dropped your major contribution from the rep calc and is only basing it of the last, minor, contribution.  I voted to reopen as I do not think the dupe applies here

Comment: @NathanOliver [I think you're correct.](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/6270) There's something very wrong with that contributors page. If that page indicates how the system has recalced the rep, that would definitely explain the issue.

Comment: @Kendra Wow, that does not look right.  How do you get to that page?

Comment: @NathanOliver The link structure is in [the reputation recalc announcement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334551/documentation-reputation-update-is-live) under the heading "Inspecting Contributors" and the easiest way to get to one for one example is to go to that example's edit history and alter the URL from there. AFAIK there is no readily available link for it anywhere.

Comment: @Kendra Thanks for the info.  Looks like I will need another user script.

Comment: @NathanOliver, That's what bookmarklets are for: `javascript:(function(){var sep=/^((?:[^/]+)\/(?:\/[^/]+){2})(?:\/[^/]+)(\/[^/]+)(?:\/[^/]+)(?:(\/[^/]+)(?:\/[^/]+))?$/.exec(location.href);var add='/topic'+sep[2];if(sep[3]){add='/example'+sep[3];}window.open(sep[1]+'/contributors'+add);})()`

Comment: @Kendra, The above bookmarklet (opens the doc's contributors page in a new tab) is intended for use from viewing either the [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/213/hello-world#t=20160909181038632691), or [example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/213/hello-world/3675/original-hello-world-in-kr-c#t=201609091811591704914). Obviously, if you so desired, it could be modified to also work from viewing the example's edit history page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been unable to reproduce this issue - we've made a [plethora](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AQ_eKVIqKE) of bug fixes around contributions, so it's highly possible this was fixed.

In investigating this, I did uncover some other rep bugs (not documentation-specific), which I'll be fixing next week, when I'm on general bug duty.  If anything comes up there that relates to this issue, I'll update.

Comment: I confirm It was fixed thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

We have some internal reports for auditing recalculations. The change you noticed was probably from October 27:

> Topics Rolled by DocProposedChange.Id = 106492 Approval old: **2752**, new: **2384**

That's a drop of 368 reputation, which is not too different from the ~400 you reported.

The specific change mentioned in the log is [this rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/106492). However, your only contribution to the topic seems to be [this trivial edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/69420) on July 31. Since the rollback was to the Oct. 11 revision, this shouldn't have changed your contributor status even if it *were* major.

My best guess is that you were awarded reputation under the old system that was removed when the contributor list was recalculated after the rollback. Two difficulties with that theory, however:

1. Why wasn't this accounted for in the global recalc that occurred immediately after the reputation system was changed?
2. How could the total difference in reputation be 368? The only thing that sorta makes sense is a loss of 370 from upvotes and a gain of +2 for the approved change.

Since I've hit the limit of my ability to track this down, I'll ask a developer to take a look. It would be better to correct all of these cases at once than wait for an unrelated rollback to catch the problem.