# Documentation bug? Contributors breakdown does not match revision history, improvement request reappeared shortly after edit was approved

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, documentation

For [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/typescript/2023/interfaces/6619/add-functions-or-properties-to-an-existing-interface#t=201609122345570387116), [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/typescript/revisions/2023?exampleId=6619) shows that 3 edits were made after example was created:

- artem edited 5 hours ago. View Edit  View Topic
- Robin edited Jul 29 at 10:50. View Edit  View Topic
- Sunnyok edited Jul 22 at 14:53. View Edit  View Topic
- Sunnyok added an example Jul 22 at 7:34.

But Robin's edit is missing from [contributors breakdown page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/6619):

```
 2 Active Contributors

 1 Major Contributors
     Sunnyok since Jul 22 at 7:34 (2 changes)

 1 Minor Contributors
     artem since 5 hours ago (1 changes)
```

Also, for this example an improvement request is shown:

```
Improvements requested by ABabin:

This example is not helpful and should be edited or deleted. - Aug 16 at 4:19
```

However, this request was supposed to be handled by my edit done "5 hours ago", and I remember that after the edit was approved, this request went away. But now it's shown again with the same date - Aug 16 - which is almost a month ago.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

We don't show users who add [20 or fewer characters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333420/documentation-update-august-29th) to an example on the contributors report because they are not considered contributors for the purpose of repuation.

I'm not sure what happened with the Improvement Request. However, you do need to indicate that you are handling it by either using the request's edit button:

[image: Improvement Request Edit]

or indicating that your edit handles the request after you started writing your draft:

[image: Handle requests]

If you forget or notice an edit solved the problem, feel free to dismiss the request.

Comment: Ok, I counted the characters, excluding whitespace and quotes, in [that change](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/62997). I got -30/+43 in the title, and -38/+46 in the body - so the total is +21. Do changes in the title count towards 20 char limit? Anyway, IMO here is one example that edit can be a significant improvement without changing character count.

Comment: And for my change - yes I did start my edit by clicking on 'Edit Example' button on that improvement request - going to dismiss it now.

Comment: Also, it would be nice to be able to add a reason why I dismissed it